# SQLAlchemy: filter by relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, `User` and `Object`, which have a one-to-many relationship (a `User` can have many `objects` ).

How can I filter for users that have at least one object, in a pep8 compliant way?

This code works, but is not pep8-compliant:

```
query = session.query(User.id)
query = query.filter(User.objects != None)
```

The documentation mentions using `isnot`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators

But the following code gives rise to a not implemented error.

```
query = session.query(User.id)
query = query.filter(User.objects.isnot(None))
```

Comment: use `is not None` instead of `!= None`

Comment: I'm pretty sure SQLAlchemy doesn't work with `is not`, though it's a valid Python construct.

Comment: ah okey.   I just pointed out the obvious non-PEP8.

Comment: Given that `sqlalchemy` uses operator overloading in to make it user-friendly to construct queries, it is not possible to make comparisons to NULL PEP8 compliant, as python does not allow overriding `is` (`is` is a keyword in python, not an operator)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you pointed out, `isnot` is not implemented for relationships, but only for simple columns.

As for relationships, there is a general even more powerful construct [`any(criterion, ...)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any).

In your case you can write the PEP8-compliant code below, which will produce exactly the same `SQL` as in your question:

```
q = session.query(User.id)
q = q.filter(User.objects.any())
```

But it also allows you to do more complicated queries, like: *return Users, which do **not** have objects with `value > 100`*:

```
q = session.query(User.id)
q = q.filter(~User.objects.any(Object.value > 100))
```

Comment: To reverse the condition you can just simply do `session.query(MyClass).filter(~MyClass.somereference.any())`, from the documentation at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any

Answer (score -5):

As you may know, in Django such filtering can be done in [simple, declarative way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')
```

And I always dreamt to have something like this in SQLAlchemy.

Good news for you: few weeks ago, **I created package for that**: https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins#django-like-queries

Also package contains very useful batteries: **Active Record for SQLAlchemy** as well as nested eager loading and readable `__repr__`.